# Access config.properties from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, properties-file

I've created an Android project which is being stored on GitHub as a public repository. The project contains an API key which shouldn't be made viewable to the public. In order to prevent the public from seeing the key, I've placed it in the config.properties file. In AndroidManifest.xml, the key value contains dummy data. To run the application for testing purposes, I'm currently pasting the key into the manifest before launching and replacing it with the dummy data before I commit any changes to GitHub.

My question, how do I access the property `api.key` in config.properties from AndroidManifest.xml? Idealy, when the gradle file builds the project, the api.key value is inserted into AndroidManifest.xml, but is never seen on GitHub because the .gitignore file does not allow .properties files to be committed.